# typescript scroll position

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular UI code, I have a component class that calls a  like below

app.component.html

```
//...
<div class="banner">
    <p-dialog [(visible)]="displayCOI" styleClass="coiDialog" [contentStyle]="{'overflow-y': 'hidden'}" [modal]="true" [style]="{width: '75vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000" [showHeader]="false"
        [draggable]="false" [resizable]="false">  
        <coi (notify)="onCoIAccept($event)"></coi>
    </p-dialog>
</div>

...///
```

coi.component.html looks like below

```
<div>
<div class="row" style="padding: 10px 0px">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p align="center"><b>Instructions</b></p>                        
    <br>...//
    </div>
    <div #scrollDiv id="scrollDiv" class="col-sm-6" style="height:350px; overflow-y: scroll;" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [scrollable]="true" [value]="usersLi" [(selection)]="selectedUsersLi"  dataKey="id">
    //....
    ..///
    </p-table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div align="center">
        <button pButton type="button" label="Accept" [disabled]="disableAccept" (click)="close()" class="ui-button-rounded"></button>&nbsp;
        </a>
    </div>
</dv>
</div>
```

coi.component.ts code is as below:

```
export class coiComponent  {
  @ViewChild("scrollDiv") scrollDiv: ElementRef;
  disableAccept: boolean = false;
  
  ngOnInit():void { 
    this.keys = Object.keys(this.propertyObj); 
    this._utilService.convertKeysToHeader(this.keys,this.cols);
    this.disableAccept = true;    
    this.loadRecords();
  }
  
  
  onScroll(event: any) { 
    // visible height + pixel scrolled >= total height 
    if (event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop >= event.target.scrollHeight) {
        this.disableAccept = false;
        console.log("End");
    }
  }
  
   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log("ngOnChanges" , changes);
    for ( const propName in changes){
        let change = changes[propName];
        if ( propName == 'coi'){
            // console.log('CHANGED...DO HERE');
            console.log(this.scrollDiv.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
            console.log(this.scrollDiv.nativeElement.scrollHeight); 
        }
    
    }
    
    }
}
```

As you can see the modal is divided into 3 DIV. `1. instrucations, 2: table, 3. Accept button`
The modal by itself has a fixed height and scroll hidden. The div with table has a fixed height and overflow scroll and it works perfectly. Now the table can be with 30-50 records so vertical scrolling is enabled. I want the accept button on the 3rd div to be enabled only when the user had scrolled the table and has seen all the records. So the `function (scroll)="onScroll($event)"` enables only when the scroll is scrolled completely and it works perfectly.

my question is Some users may see less than 5-10 records which means scroll wouldn't be enabled for those users and accept also need to be enabled for them. Any suggestion on how to do this, please? I tried adding an id for the div tag called "scrollDiv" and #scrollDiv and passing this as an ElementRef and on ngOnChange  trying to get the offsetHeight and scrollHeight but I get value '0' on all the cases.` Can someone help me with this?

I have updated my question. Please give some suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give you a running idea, then you can understand and apply it to your case. You can check [at this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-jepsen-fixuk?file=/src/app/app.component.ts).

**Explanation of the example**

In the component you have 4 important things to consider:

- `isActionDisabled` a variable that says if your action should be disabled or not
- `@ViewChild('containerElement') containerElement` a refer to the scrollable container of the table
- `onScrollContainer` a method that's executed when you scroll the `containerElement`
- `disableByScroll` a method that changes the value of `isActionDisabled` according to the position of the scrollbar of the `containerElement`. If it's on bottom `isActionDisabled` is `false` otherwise is `true`.

The most important method is `disableByScroll`:

```
disableByScroll(): void {
  if (this.containerElement) {
    const element = this.containerElement.nativeElement;
    this.isActionDisabled = !(
      element.scrollTop ===
      element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight
    );
  } else {
    this.isActionDisabled = true;
  }
}
```

Please read this [article](https://medium.com/@jbbpatel94/difference-between-offsetheight-clientheight-and-scrollheight-cfea5c196937) to understand what I did.
`disableByScroll` is called each time a scroll event is called on `containerElement`

```
onScrollContainer(): void {
  this.disableByScroll();
}
```

and after view init

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.disableByScroll();
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

That is useful if you have a number of items that do not activate the scrollbar. Please, read this [guide to understand the lifecycle events](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) of an Angular application. As you can see I called a method `detectChanges` of the [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef). Reading that guide you'll understand why.

About the template, it's pretty simple and you can figure it out.

Comment: thank you . can you please see my updated code and edits please?

Comment: I just edited it. I've created a playground for you so you can apply it to your code. What I did is to consider if the scrollbar thumb is at the bottom and you can know it checking if  `scrollTop = scrollHeight - clientHeight`. You can do the same check to enable or disable the button if no scrollbar is present. In that case `scrollTop` is `0` and `scrollHeight` is equal `clientHeight` (so `0`). Anyway, I added some links so you can understand it better.

Comment: @ Francesco Lisandro thank you. But when i get the clientHeight, scrollHeight, offsetHeight it all says 200 on page load. Do you know why?

Comment: It's a problem not related to it. Probably it's a syntax problem.

Comment: this.cdr.detectChanges(); made the difference thank you. @Francesco Lisandro